# Can't access sinatra service outside of container

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I am getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the browser after lunching the Sinatra container in docker. If I connect to the docker container and run `curl localhost:4567` it works, but outside of the container - doesn't

web.rb

```rb
require 'sinatra'
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
    'Hello world!'
end
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.0.2
EXPOSE 4567
COPY ./web.rb .
RUN gem install sinatra
RUN gem install puma
CMD ["ruby", "web.rb"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was in binding application to 0.0.0.0 host

```
require 'sinatra'
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
    'Hello world!'
end
```

Comment: I was debugging the problem for a while, thank you for that!